# Can I make flexbox elements flex-wrap 2 by 2 instead of 1 by 1?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex div that has flex-wrap: wrap and 4 children. When I resize the window, the children elements start to wrap to the next line, but right now they're wrapping to the next line 1 by 1. I am curious if it is possible to make them wrap to the next line 2 by 2. So if there's not enough width for 4 elements, I want 2 of them to wrap to the next line instead of only one. Is this possible with flex?

```css
    .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .child {
        background-color: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: put them inside extra wrappers (2 by 2)

Comment: Do you need `.child` to be fixed px width?

Answer (score 0):

I have specified media query for smaller device to show atleast 2 box. I added flex-basis CSS attribute to show 2 by 2.

```css
 .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .child {
        background-color: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 769px){
.child {
 flex-basis: 35%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```